# How to dump unknown stream in ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I have some video file in which audio is some unknown to ffmpeg format: *g722.1* (incorrectly recognized as aac):

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'input.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:34.00, start: 71056.228111, bitrate: 179 kb/s
  Program 1
    Stream #0:0[0x21]: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720, 10 fps, 12.50 tbr, 90k tbn, 20 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x22]: Audio: aac (SSR) ([146][0][0][0] / 0x0092), mono, fltp, 789 kb/s
```

Is it possible to extract this very track as binary data, without any processing? Then I could obviously try to convert this track with different tool. I am using ffmpeg in version *N-69498-g7620d48*.

Or maybe someone has an idea how to decode g722.1 with ffmpeg?

Comment: maybe file an ffmpeg trac for this as well [if it's being detected incorrectly] does copying it out like "-a:c copy" as aac work?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't every time I gen an error that it is not a valid aac header. It seems like ffmpeg is pretty stubborn about formats and doesn't allow me to simply dump the binary blob.

Comment: I'd ask on the ffmpeg ML or submit an ffmpeg trac [?]